# Connecting Java program to SQL server 2005 using JTDS

Tags: java, jtds

I have made a java program (on NetBeans IDE 7.0 beta version) and I want to connect it with the database named as school. This database is created on SQL server 2005 in windows authentication mode and by running SQL management express studio as an administrator. I have created the DSN which is named as "mm".Here host name is "monika-pc".But I am getting the errors. Kindly look at my code please.

```
package javaapplication2;


import java.sql.*;

public class JavaApplication2
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int i=0;
try
{       
String str="Select fname from students";
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://monika-pc/mm");
        System.out.println("Connection open");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(str);
        System.out.println("fname\t");
        while(i<3)
        {
            rs.next();
            String lname=rs.getString("lname");
            System.out.println(lname);
            i++;

        }
            con.close();    
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and I am getting the following errors..

```
run:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:15)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Can anyone solve this problem please.Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Please stop **SHOUTING** at us.  We are not DEAF.

Comment: *" want to connect it with the database named as school."*  Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jtds jar for ms sql as a library in your IDE
Also ensure that this is the correct name of the driver to be loaded